# How can I uninstall a site that was installed as a Web Application?

Tags: epiphany, apps

I installed a site as a web application in Epiphany (in the upper right gear icon) as a shortcut that I could then keep in my dock. However, the site is just a rendered static page with no clickable links (iCloud site, so probably a security feature, as other "shortcut" sites are active/working).

What I need to know is how to UNINSTALL this shortcut. I've removed it from dock and right-clicked the app I saved, but there is no uninstall option. There's no "drag to recycle/trash" option either. I've looked in all sub-folders and the shortcut isn't listed. I just want to remove it. I'd like a way to remove it from desktop/apps folder without going into Terminal but happily will. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a bit hidden, but you can remove added web apps in Epiphany itself. In the location entry at the top, type `about:applications` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see a screen like this. Find the installed web app you'd like to remove, and hit its **Delete** button.

[image: Installed web applications in Epiphany]

We've reported [an issue upstream in Epiphany itself](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/issues/958) to hopefully make this process more discoverable.

Comment: This method leaves behind a .desktop file in the user's .local/share/applications folder, and it still appears in Slingshot, but without an icon. After deleting the leftover .desktop file, all seems to be well.

Comment: The next time the desktop launcher cache is generated (so after installing or uninstalling another app, logging out, or rebooting), the leftover icon goes away. That might be a bug with Slingshot, but this is the only officially-supported way of uninstalling web apps according to Epiphany developers.

Comment: Yes, not really an issue. Restarting Wingpanel also seems to do the trick.

Comment: "This method leaves behind a .desktop file in the user's .local/share/applications folder"

That's fixed in 3.28.6, see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/commit/0ef8ad5b5ce0df33a4f2dd5df1b6002d8bb34e9f

Comment: @Vlad Pop; from 5.0 the desktop files is not present anymore, probably it's a fixed bug

Answer (score 0):

There's no intuitive way of removing these shortcuts, unfortunately.

For now the easiest method is to use [AppEditor](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/) to remove the shortcut and  manually removing the app by deleting the associated `app-epiphany[...]` folder from `~/.config/epiphany`.

If you didn't want to use AppEditor you should be able to delete the `.desktop` file from `~/.local/share/applications` for the same effect. It just might be nicer to have the visual option (or easily hide it to be restored later if need be).

Comment: Since there's a built-in method using Epiphany, I think that would be a better solution than directing users to install third-party apps or manually edit config files.